# How to Update table after retrieving and returning the result to the method head in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public ArrayList<Task> getTaskDao(Contributor contributor , Task task) {

    getConnection();
    query = session.createQuery("Select t.taskId,t.task from Task t where status='NOTALLOCATED'");
    ArrayList<Task> tasklist = (ArrayList<Task>) query.list();
    logger.info(tasklist.size());
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(tasklist.get(0));
    return (ArrayList<Task>) list;
```

Now I want to update `status = 'ALLOCATED'` in the task table inside same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically allocate the status, for this you can pass the status as a parameter and later in query update as the below code.

```
public ArrayList getTaskDao(Contributor contributor, Task task, String status) 
{  
    getConnection();

    Query query = session.createQuery("Select t.taskId,t.task from Task t where status='"+status+"'");
    ArrayList tasklist = (ArrayList) query.list();
    logger.info(tasklist.size());
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(tasklist.get(0));
    return (ArrayList) list;
}
```

Hence, the query will work for both the status i.e, 'ALLOCATED' and 'NOTALLOCATED' by calling the below code:

```
getTaskDao(contributor, task,"ALLOCATED") ;
getTaskDao(contributor, task,"NOTALLOCATED") ;
```

If the status is a property of task then you can use the below query.

```
public ArrayList getTaskDao(Contributor contributor, Task task) 
{  
    getConnection();

    Query query = session.createQuery("Select t.taskId,t.task from Task t where status='"+task.getStatus()+"'");
    ArrayList tasklist = (ArrayList) query.list();
    logger.info(tasklist.size());
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(tasklist.get(0));
    return (ArrayList) list;
}
```

Comment: Hello Rohit thanks for your replay and time but my question is after returning the list suppose i want to set the status column value as 'allocated' where current value is 'notallocated' then what should i do?

Comment: Why you need to change the value to  'notallocated'? It's a method(getTaskDao). whenever you want to change the value of status to 'notallocated' just call that method by using getTaskDao(contributor, task,"NOTALLOCATED") ; No one is going to use that query directly, one have to call that method first.

Comment: actually i am getting the task where status is 'notallocated' and upto that it is ok, but now i want to change the status to 'allocated' as soon as the task is fetched.

Comment: like if i try to execute task.setStatus("ALLOCATED"); after that it is giving not-null property references a null or transient value : model.Task.task exception in the terminal

Comment: If the status is a property of task then you can use the above additional query: task.getStatus()